# How to fix Magento's incorrect Soap V2 location address

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap

I'm trying to use Magento's SOAP V2 api. The URI path for the API is http://www.example.com/api/v2_soap.  When I'm making my request I'm using http://www.example.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl.  The request correctly shows the wsdl xml file but if I try to run this code from the command line I get an error that says 'looks like we got no XML document':

```
        try{
                $client = new SoapClient('http://www.example.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl');
                $session = $client->login('username', 'apiKey');

                var_dump($session);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        var_dump($e->getMessage());
        var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());
        var_dump($client->__getLastResponse());
    }
```

I believe I've narrowed this down to the soap:address in the wsdl file.  The location value is set to the index.php file rather than the api path or the api.php file.

```
<service name="MagentoService">
  <port name="Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPort" binding="typens:Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerBinding">
  <soap:address location="http://www.example.com/index.php/?type=v2_soap"/>
 </port>
</service>
```

I can't quite find where this url is generated or how to change it to the correct value.

In addition to using http://www.example.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl I've also tried using http://www.example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl as I've seen mentioned in other questions, but that doesn't have any effect on the address location value.

Any help to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error message you are getting is thrown by PHP, not Magento.

Comment: Did you solve this? I think that isn't the correct way to connect to SOAP v2

Comment: The URL is generated in: /app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Wsdl/Config/Base.php around line 57 as reporter here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74753/incorrect-location-url-returned-by-v2-soap-wsdl

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have created users and assigned role, below article will guide to do so, I have also included sample php code which works well

http://siddharthvaghasia.com/2014/12/10/enable-magento-soap-api-from-backend-to-enable-client-application-to-connect-with-magento-store/

Now to be specific about your questions, do check your .htaccess file redirection rules, it might be possible some of redirection might be sending request to different url than you are intentded to do.

Comment: The page no longer exists.

Comment: Edited link in answer...please check now..