# Incorrect Location URL returned by V2 SOAP WSDL

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap

When fetching the V2 WSDL via this URL:

```
www.example.com/shop/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1
```

It is defining the wrong URL for requests:

```
<service name="MagentoService">
  <port name="Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPort" binding="typens:Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerBinding">
    <soap:address location="http://example.com/shop/index.php/?type=v2_soap"/>
  </port>
</service>
```

As you can see above, it is returning this URL:

```
www.example.com/shop/index.php/?type=v2_soap
```

Although it should be:

```
www.example.com/shop/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/
```

I've hunted down through a lot of the Magento core code and I believe that value get set in
    /app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Wsdl/Config/Base.php
around line 53:

```
    // set up default WSDL template variables
    $this->_wsdlVariables = new Varien_Object(
        array(
            'name' => 'Magento',
            'url'  => htmlspecialchars(Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_query' => $queryParams)))
        )
    );
```

This part is what appears to be failing:

```
Mage::getUrl('*/*/*' ...
```

If I change that to:

```
Mage::getUrl('api/v2_soap/index' ...
```

the correct URL is returned.

This question appears to be describing the exact same problem, but there was never an answer for it:

- [How to fix Magento's incorrect Soap V2 location address](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53398/how-to-fix-magentos-incorrect-soap-v2-location-address)

Thanks in advance for any help!

### UPDATE

Although I've yet to find a permanent solution to this issue, I have found a temporary solution after searching around a bit. Essentially, I extend the SoapClient class and override the __doRequest method as a means of intercepting requests and tweaking the location URL before the request is sent:

```
class SoapClientLocation extends \SoapClient
{
    public function __doRequest( $req, $location, $action, $version = SOAP_1_1, $one_way = NULL )
    {
        $location = str_replace( '?type=v2_soap', 'api/v2_soap/index/', $location, $one_way );
        return parent::__doRequest( $req, $location, $action, $version );
    }
}

 $this->client = new SoapClientLocation( $this->config['api']['url'] );
```

Comment: System -> configuration -> Web -> Url Options -> Auto-redirect to Base URL. Set that to 'No'

Comment: I've tried that a few different times and it appears to have no effect.

Answer (score 2):

It can be two issues:

1. Use `www.example.com/shop/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl` instead of
   `www.example.com/shop/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1` (note the added
   `index.php`)
2. Make sure that you disabled `error_reporting`/`display_errors` in
   your `index.php`.

Long note on the last point:
The `SoapClient` isn't a browser and therefore doesn't send cookies, Magento in turn likes cookies and therefore Magento trows a Notice (when error_reporting is enabled), the notice makes your XML invalid/doesn't even make it load. (`SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't find <definitions>`)

Comment: I tried adding index.php/ to the URL and it didn't appear to help. I'm going to try looking into the error reporting. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that

```
Mage_Api_Controller_Action::preDispatch()
```

Sets the current store to 'admin' (more information in Alan's blog post http://alanstorm.com/magento_api_adapater_xml_rpc)

If you have 'Auto-redirect to Base URL' set, then the API won't be accessible.

My solution was listen to

```
controller_front_init_before
```

And zero out that config node if the URI contains 'api'.  I.e.

```
public function controllerFrontInitBefore($observer) {
    if (stristr(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRequestUri(), 'api')) {
        Mage::getConfig()->setNode('stores/' . Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode() . '/web/url/redirect_to_base', 0);
    }
}
```